# Вывод значений из mysql

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Подскажите, вывожу из бд значения в `option`, проблема в том что выводятся все значения из строки marka, получается много `option` с одинаковым значением в данном случае Toyota...Пробовал добавить в mysql строку `marka_id` и записывать туда только одно значение дальше не трогать, но появились пустые поля `option`, может как то попробывать выводить связку строк id + marka, только вот не знаю как это реализовать.

```
<select class="filtr__select" id="idcat">
     <option id="marka-avto">марка</option>
     <?php
         //Выводим категории и ее ID
         while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
         {
             $id = $row['id']; // иднтификатор
             $marka = $row['marka']; 

             echo "<option value=\"$id\">$marka</option>"; 

         }
     ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Покажите ваш результат и что должно получиться, и желательно еще сам `$result`, сам запрос к бд.

Comment: Если коротко , есть бд, в этой бд 5строк (id, marka, marka_id, model, url ), заполняю эти строки бд так: id : 1 , marka : toyota , marka_id : toyota , model : camry , url : http/.... // Получается что в option выводистя значение marka(toyota) и у меня этих option столько сколько и товаров, а мне нужно чтобы option тойоты был один(дальше будут другие значения к примеру honda).   $query = "select * from filtr_db";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

Comment: Ну я знаю, что поможет вам, но не понятно тогда как вы будете использовать `$id` в `option`? Например `id : 1 , marka : toyota` и `id : 2 , marka : toyota`, что вы дальше собираетесь с этим делать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у вас в БД `'marka' == 'marka_id'`, то логичнее ничего я не придумал:

Запрос можно сделать так:

`SELECT DISTINCT(marka) FROM filtr_db`

а потом в цикле `echo "<option value=\"$marka\">$marka</option>";`

`$id = $row['id'];` - удалить, от него смысла нет, ибо у вас получается что 2 одинаковые марки имеют разные `id`

Comment: Так не работает...Страница вообще не загружается с таким запросом

Comment: @ilyaaa521 А что пишет? Ошибки есть какие, или нет?

Comment: Я вижу один вариант пока что, переделать бд создать отдельно таблицу marka, только вот незнаю как потом интегрировать marka с model

Comment: Ошибок вообще нет, пустая страница....

Comment: в консоле ошибка 500 GET

Comment: @ilyaaa521 ну вообще `SELECT DISTINCT marka FROM filtr_db` - работать должен, простенький запрос, тут негде накосячить. Уберите `or die(mysql_error())` и попробуйте

Comment: Заработало!Спасибо большое, скажите а в дальнейшем после того как добавлю в бд все значения можно будет реализовать что бы при клике на определенную марку подгружался список моделей из бд!?Я так понимаю нужно будет через аякс делать запрос к бд

Comment: @ilyaaa521 ну если 'живая' подгрузка, то да, через `ajax` надо будет делать :) А по поводу вашего вопроса, хоть я и считаю что у вас кривая табличка, но сделать это будет реально.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо еще раз

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/860872/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b8%d0%b7-mysql-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-ajax   дружище, выручай )