# Вывод значений из mysql через ajax

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

Есть таблица в бд(id, marka, model)
Из этой таблицы вывожу в первый список значения marka

```
<select class="filtr__select" id="idcat">
                        <option id="marka-avto">Выберите марку авто</option>
                        <?php
                            //Выводим категории и ее ID
                            while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
                            {

                            $marka = $row['marka']; 

                            echo "<option value=\"$marka\">$marka</option>";

                            }
                        ?>
                    </select>
```

второй список нужно сделать так чтобы брал значения из первого списка марок, и по этим значениям подгружал модели(тоесть в первом списке список марок, если выбор допустим пал на марку toyota, то должен подгружаться список моделей для toyota)

```
      <select class="filtr__select" id="idcat">
                            <option>модель</option>
                           <?php
                             //Выводим категории и ее ID
                             while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
                             {
                             $id = $row['id']; // иднтификатор
                             $model = $row['model']; 

                             echo "<option value=\"$id\">$model</option>";

                             }
                         ?>
                    </select>

 Подскажите как сделать так чтобы во второй список подгружались значения model конкретной марки(marka) Пробывал скрипт сам написать на аяксе но что то не получилось... 

                   <script>
                            $("#idcat").change(function(){

                                var idcat = $(this).val();
                                $.ajax({
                                    type: 'GET',      
                                    url: 'index.php',
                                    data: ['model'],
                                    success: function(data) {
                                        $('#idcat2').html(data);
                                    }
                                });
                            });

                        </script>


 Правка (полностью файл)
        <?php

        $hostname = "localhost"; 
        $username = "***"; 
        $password = "***"; 
        $dbName = "***"; 

        mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die ("Не могу         создать соединение");
        mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8') or header('Location: Error');

        mysql_select_db($dbName) or die (mysql_error());

        $query = "SELECT DISTINCT model FROM filtr_db";
        $query = "SELECT DISTINCT marka FROM filtr_db";
        $result = mysql_query($query);

        ?>


       <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

         <form id="myForm">
            <div class="filtr__1">
                <div class="filtr__1__form">
                    <h1 class="filtr__1__form__title">Быстрый подбор по авто</h1>
                    <select class="filtr__select" id="idcat">
                        <option id="marka-avto">Выберите марку авто</option>
                        <?php
                            //Выводим категории и ее ID
                            while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
                            {

                            $marka = $row['marka']; 

                            echo "<option value=\"$marka\">$marka</option>";

                            }
                        ?>
                    </select>
                    <select class="filtr__select" id="idcat2">
                        <option id="model-avto">модель</option>

                    </select>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                            $('#idcat').change(function(){
                                var val = $(this).val();
                                $('#idcat2').html('');
                                $.ajax({
                                type: 'POST',
                                url: 'show.php',
                                data: {'model': val},
                                success: function(data) {
                                    var obj = JSON.parse(data);
                                    obj.forEach(function(item) {
                                        $('#idcat2').append($("<option>  </option>")
                                                    .attr("value",item).text(item)); 
                                    });
                                }
                                });
                            });
                    </script>

         //файл show.php

        <?php
        $hostname = "localhost"; 
        $username = "***"; 
        $password = "***"; 
        $dbName = "***"; 


        mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die ("Не могу  создать соединение");
        mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8') or header('Location: Error');

        mysql_select_db($dbName) or die (mysql_error());




        $MODEL = $_POST['model'];

       //Не забываем что должна быть обработка $MODEL
       //что-бы всякие хацкеры не могли сломать
       //например всякие mysqli_escape_string
       //если юзаем PDO prepare-execute, он сделает это за нас

          if (isset($MODEL) && !empty($MODEL)) {
          //  Используя нашу $MODEL нужно сделать
          $query = "SELECT DISTINCT model FROM filtr_db";
          $DB = mysql_query($query);
       //  запрос к БД, который вернет массив типа:
          $DB[0]['model'] = 'camry';
          $DB[1]['model'] = 'raw4';
          $DB[2]['model'] = 'corolla';
           //  Обработаем
           $DB = array_column($DB, 'model');
          // Обрабатываем потому, что нам нужен такой массив:
            // array('camry', 'raw4', 'corolla')
          //  Выводим
        echo json_encode($DB);
         } else {
          echo '[]';
        }
      ?>
```

Comment: а сам запрос к бд скините? ну т е php скрипт (у вас index.php, лучше сделать для этих целей отдельный файл, т к вам придеся получать ответ, я б тоже это делал в json). В ajax лучше передовать в JSON типе. `data: {'data':'mydata'},`

Comment: Написал выше после слова "правка" полностью файл с подключением и запросами к бд, желательно сделать все в одном файле если это возможно

Comment: в JSON так же не желательно, работал только с бд...

Comment: шо тут, опять запара?

Comment: Да, без тебя опять никак дружище, выручай благодарности моей не будет предела ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я лишь покажу в общих чертах, как это все должно выглядеть и работать, допилите до совершенства сами:

Итак, у нас есть HTML:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <!-- Наш исходный idcat -->
    <select id="idcat">
    <option selected disabled>Выберете марку</option>
    <option value="toyota">toyota</option>
    <option value="lada">lada</option>
    </select>
    <!-- Второй idcat, всплывающий -->
    <select id="idcat2" style="display: none;">
    </select>

    <!-- JS -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#idcat').change(function(){
            var val = $(this).val();
            $('#idcat2').show();
            $('#idcat2').html('');
            $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'test.php',
            data: {'model': val},
            success: function(data) {
                var obj = JSON.parse(data);
                obj.forEach(function(item) {
                    $('#idcat2').append(new Option(item, item));
                    // либо так
                    //$('#idcat2').append($("<option></option>")
                    //            .attr("value",item).text(item)); 
                });
            }
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

При выборе первого селекта, отправляется ajax на `test.php` который выглядит как-то так:

```
<?php

$MODEL = $_POST['model'];

//Не забываем что должна быть обработка $MODEL
//что-бы всякие хацкеры не могли сломать
//например всякие mysqli_escape_string
//если юзаем PDO prepare-execute, он сделает это за нас

if (isset($MODEL) && !empty($MODEL)) {
    //  Используя нашу $MODEL нужно сделать
    //  запрос к БД, который вернет массив типа:
    $DB[0]['model'] = 'camry';
    $DB[1]['model'] = 'raw4';
    $DB[2]['model'] = 'corolla';
    //  Обработаем
    $DB = array_column($DB, 'model');
    // Обрабатываем потому, что нам нужен такой массив:
    // array('camry', 'raw4', 'corolla')
    //  Выводим
    echo json_encode($DB);
} else {
    echo '[]';
}
```

Все это дело рабочее, до красотульки доведете сами.

Comment: Выводит пустое поле в idcat2... возможно я в файле show.php не правильный запрос прописал, посмотри после правки выложил код

Comment: @ilyaaa521 чтобы в `файл show.php` выполнить запрос, там сперва надо подключиться к БД, а этот элемент отсутствует.

Comment: @ilyaaa521 `<script type="text/javascript">` не должен находиться внутри `select`. Вы видите как у меня на примере?

Comment: Подредактировал, все равно такая же беда..

Comment: @ilyaaa521 мне там надо за вас сесть и написать? `$result = mysql_query($query);` переименовать надо в `$DB = mysql_query($query);`

Comment: @ilyaaa521 скорее всего запрос должен быть другой, все это дело должно быть ПОСЛЕ `if (isset($MODEL) && !empty($MODEL)) {` а не ДО. надо убедиться что `show.php` находится там-же где и основной файл, иначе в ajax правильно указать путь.

Comment: Все не надо за меня писать, просто с базами не работал поэтому вникаю// переименовал так же без изменений, скажите а скрипт правильно написал?Если да то дальше сам попробую...

Comment: @ilyaaa521 Вам чтобы проверить, работает у вас ajax или нет, просто надо вставить в `show.php` мой пример, он рабочий, выводит только фиксированные поля, но выводит, если у вас в `idcat2` появятся модели - значит работает и вам нужно просто добить `show.php`

Comment: Вставил ваш пример, ничего не изменилось, выводит так же один пустой option, show.php находится в той же папке что и index

Comment: @ilyaaa521 изменения будут только после выбора в `idcat`

Comment: я понимаю, но даже после выбора, не происходят изменения

Comment: @ilyaaa521 если вы в `idcat` выбираете и ничего не меняется, значит проблема еще и в html коде. F12 - консолька и смотрите что там не так, можно пошагово, возьмите в той-же директории создайте еще один файлик, например `test.php` вставьте туда мой код html, проверьте, должно все работать (не забываем в ajax путь указать). Если работает - то постепенно вставляйте туда свои куски и смотрите где что и как не работает.

Comment: Изменяется idcat2 при клике по idcat (option со словом 'модель'  меняется на пустой option) но значения другие не появляются, может все таки проблема в запросе sql

Comment: ваш код html вставил в новый файл, и все равно нечего не происходит, я так понимаю ajax не работает, быть может попробовать все сделать в одном файле, дело в том что я пробовал конект установить с бд через отдельный файл и так же не получилось подключиться, пришлось прописывать в index настройки подключения к бд

Comment: @ilyaaa521 ajax не может не работать, т.е. вы создали в ОДНОЙ папке test.html (первый мой файл), там-же test.php (второй мой файл), вы это дело запустили на хосте и у вас не работает? не может такого быть, у меня-то все работает -.-