# Вывод из бд знайчений через ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Подскажите где ошибка, есть код(фильтр) который выводить 2 значения из бд(marka, model) марка выводится нормально, модель должна подгружаться через ajax в зависимости от выбранной марки, но почему то не срабатывает...вот код:

```
   <?php

 include_once "templates/megawebshop/html/com_virtuemart/category    /show.php";

$hostname = "localhost"; 
$username = "***"; 
$password = "***"; 
$dbName = "***"; 


 mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die ("Не могу создать    соединение");
 mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8') or header('Location: Error');

 mysql_select_db($dbName) or die (mysql_error());


 $query = "SELECT DISTINCT marka FROM filtr_db";
 $result = mysql_query($query);

 ?>
```

```
        <form id="myForm">
            <div class="filtr__1">
                <div class="filtr__1__form">
                    <h1 class="filtr__1__form__title">Быстрый подбор по авто</h1>
                    <select class="filtr__select" id="idcat">
                        <option id="marka-avto">Выберите марку авто</option>
                        <?php
                            //Выводим категории и ее ID
                            while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
                            {
                            $marka = $row['marka']; 
                            echo "<option value=\"$marka\">$marka</option>";
                            }
                        ?>
                    </select>

                    <select class="filtr__select" id="idcat2">
                        <option id="model-avto">модель</option>

                    </select>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                            $('#idcat').change(function(){
                                var val = $(this).val();
                                $('#idcat2').html('');
                                $.ajax({
                                type: 'POST',
                                url: 'show.php',
                                data: {'model': val},
                                success: function(data) {
                                    var obj = JSON.parse(data);
                                    obj.forEach(function(item) {
                                        $('#idcat2').append($("<option></option>").attr("value",item).text(item)); 
                                    })
                                }
                                });
                            });
                    </script>

              //файл show.php

   <?php

   $hostname = "localhost"; 
   $username = "***"; 
   $password = "***"; 
   $dbName = "****"; 


   mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die ("Не могу создать соединение");
   mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8') or header('Location: Error');

   mysql_select_db($dbName) or die (mysql_error());



     $MODEL = $_POST['model'];


    if (isset($MODEL) && !empty($MODEL)) {
    $query = "SELECT DISTINCT model FROM filtr_db";
    $DB = mysql_query($query);

    //  Обработаем
    $DB = array_column($DB, 'model');
    echo json_encode($DB);
    } else {
    echo 'error';
    }


   ?>
```

Comment: А ошибка какая-нибудь падает?

Comment: Если опять не работает, проверьте правильность путей, если ваш основной файл по такому адресу: `http://mysite.ru/file.php` то show.php должен быть по такому: `http://mysite.ru/show.php`

Comment: Нашел проблему, путь в ajax на url был не правильно прописал,прописал полностью путь и заработали ваши значения            $DB[0]['model'] = 'camry';
           $DB[1]['model'] = 'raw4';
           $DB[2]['model'] = 'corolla';   тоесть при клике сейчас выводит ваши значения сейчас 'raw4' 'corolla' 'camry' , теперь надо как то сделать что бы выводились мои значения из бд, понимаю вы не скажете как это сделать )) Но быть может укажите какой нибудь справочник где можно прочить что то по этой проблеме )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отсутствие `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` перед `<script type="text/javascript">`

**Файл 1.html**

```
<form id="myForm">
    <div class="filtr__1">
        <div class="filtr__1__form">
            <h1 class="filtr__1__form__title">Быстрый подбор по авто</h1>
            <select class="filtr__select" id="idcat">
                <option id="marka-avto">Выберите марку авто</option>
                <option value="toyota">toyota</option>
                <option value="lada">lada</option>
            </select>

            <select class="filtr__select" id="idcat2">
                <option id="model-avto">модель</option>

            </select>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                    $('#idcat').change(function(){
                        var val = $(this).val();
                        $('#idcat2').html('');
                        $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: 'test.php',
                        data: {'model': val},
                        success: function(data) {
                            var obj = JSON.parse(data);
                            obj.forEach(function(item) {
                                $('#idcat2').append($("<option></option>").attr("value",item).text(item)); 
                            })
                        }
                        });
                    });
            </script>
```

**Файл test.php**

Берем отсюда: [Вывод значений из mysql через ajax](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/860872/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B8%D0%B7-mysql-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-ajax)

```
<?php

$MODEL = $_POST['model'];

//Не забываем что должна быть обработка $MODEL
//что-бы всякие хацкеры не могли сломать
//например всякие mysqli_escape_string
//если юзаем PDO prepare-execute, он сделает это за нас

if (isset($MODEL) && !empty($MODEL)) {
    //  Используя нашу $MODEL нужно сделать
    //  запрос к БД, который вернет массив типа:
    $DB[0]['model'] = 'camry';
    $DB[1]['model'] = 'raw4';
    $DB[2]['model'] = 'corolla';
    //  Обработаем
    $DB = array_column($DB, 'model');
    // Обрабатываем потому, что нам нужен такой массив:
    // array('camry', 'raw4', 'corolla')
    //  Выводим
    echo json_encode($DB);
} else {
    echo '[]';
}
```

И все работает -.-

Comment: Выдает []  )))) else {}